# Как добавить свое приложение в автозагрузку Android?

Tags: android, java

Как добавить свое приложение в автозагрузку Android?

Answer (score 2):

Подписаться на событие Boot Completed или SD Card Available. Зависит от того, в какую память устанавливается приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам стоит искать по словам [android boot completed](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=android%20boot%20completed)
или посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056570/how-to-autostart-an-android-application) готовое решение

Answer (score 1):

В Манифест добавляем

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Создаем `receiver` из `BroadcastReceiver` что бы срабатывал при включении телефона. Тут используется `AlarmManager` для запуска приложения.

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pi);
}}
```

и конечно нужно прописать

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".receivers.BootUpReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

в manifest'е, для захвата события `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`